# Store the assert failure result in a variable

Tags: groovy, assertions

I'm new to groovy and I have doubt. Lets say I have this statement:

```
assert "king" == "kin"
```

which will give me the assert failure as

```
Assertion failed: 

assert "king" == "kin" 
              | 
              false
```

and stops the program. But what I want is, store the result (the failure message, if any say in `GString`) and proceed with the program.

Is that possible to do so?

Comment: whoa, the whole point of `assert` is to stop the program :) can't you simply write `def assertion = "king" == "kin"` ?

Comment: No i'm trying to create a report of my failure asserts, so thats the reason I want to store the information some where and the report get these information. . .

Comment: but do you want to use the `assert` keyword, or are you willing to use some other feature that'll do the job? I'm thinking about logging etc.

Comment: Why You need it? For testing? Maybe there's a framework that will gather all assertions for You?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch the `AssertionError` exception. Something like this:

```
try {
  assert ["hello"] == ["A"]
}
catch(AssertionError e) {
  result = e.getMessage()
}
println  result
```

This should work. 
​